# Time Efficiency of NSRegularExpression

Tags: objective-c, regex, performance, nsregularexpression

Just curious. Does anyone know the time efficiency of an NSRegularExpression using the method matchesForString:options:error? I have read up online the efficiency of other implementations but I have yet to find anything specifically about NSRegularExpression.

http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/01/20/efficiency-of-regular-expressions/

For example, given the regular expression: `\b(?:x1|x2|...xn)\b` where the x1, x2 ...xn is a set of n different simple letter patterns, what is the time complexity of that search?

Comment: It's entirely dependent on the complexity of the regular expression.

Comment: There are free Internet tools that can benchmark your regex. It won't map perfectly to the NSRegularExpression implementation  but all that really matters is differences in orders of magnitude. First though, you should ask yourself if this will actually be the bottleneck in your application. If not, use the cleanest, most maintainable solution.

Comment: Building on what @CrimsonChris said, until there is a performance problem write the clearest code possible. If there is a performance problem examine it in Instruments, find the culprit and fix. Pre-obtimization is a tremendous loss of time that could be better spent. Almost always the culprit is unexpected code.